# mongo - accessing a key-value field while filtering

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have these data:

```
myMap = {
  "2": "facing",
  "3": "not-facing"
  "1": "hidden"
}  
   
 

stages [
 {
   "k": 1,
   "v": "hidden"
 },
 {
   "k": 2,
   "v": "facing"
 },
 {
   "k": 3,
   "v": "not-facing"
 }
]
```

and a aggregate query but, I'm missing a syntax to dynamically fetch the map data:

```
db.MyCollection.aggregate()
   .addFields({
      myMaps:  myMap 
   })
   .addFields({
     stages: stages
    })
   .addFields({
     process: {
         $filter: {
            input: stages,
            as: stageData,
            cond: {$eq: [$$stageData.v, $myMaps[$$stageData.k]]} 
         }
      }
    })
```

As you may already note, this syntax: `$myMaps[$$stageData.k]` doesn't work, how should I access the `myMaps` based on the value of the `k` in `stageData` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- like your query set mymap and stages as extra field
- mymapKeys is an extra field added (you can `$unset` is in the end)
- filter the stages, and if `stage.k` is contained in mymapKeys we keep that member

*not sure if this is what you need, but looks like from your query
in mongodb query language we dont have `getField(doc,$$k)` we only have `getField(doc,constant_string)` which cant be used in your case,
so it costs here more than a hashmap lookup, here its like linear cost (check if member in the array). For arrays we have `$getElementAt(array,$$k)` if those numbers are always in sequence, 1,2,3 etc you might be able to use arrays instead of objects

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=629cb1b491b564fc1e7e9594)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": {"mymap": {"2": "facing", "3": "not-facing", "1": "hidden"}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"mymapKeys": 
     {"$map": {"input": {"$objectToArray": "$mymap"}, "in": "$$this.k"}}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"stages": 
     [{"k": 1, "v": "hidden"}, {"k": 2, "v": "facing"},
       {"k": 3, "v": "not-facing"}]}},
 {"$set": 
   {"process": 
     {"$filter": 
       {"input": "$stages",
        "cond": {"$in": [{"$toString": "$$this.k"}, "$mymapKeys"]}}}}}])
```

Comment: but, they're not always serial though, I deliberately put them randomly, some values like e.g. `1`  could also be missing in the map

Comment: stages.k that are missing from the mymapKeys, will be filtered out, this keeps only the stages.k that are keys also in the mymap, you tried it and doesnt do what you need? If it doesnt if you can give sample data, and expected output